# Clean up code with multiple toggle states in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, coding-style, antd

I have a couple of buttons with `antd` library and want to add the loading state for each. I create multiple states to control those loadings

`const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);`

`const [loadingSave, setLoadingSave] = useState(false); //for save button`

`const [loadingDelete, setLoadingDelete] = useState(false); //for delete button`

`const [loadingDownload, setLoadingDownload] = useState(false); //for download button`

This works but it seems my code is quite messy. If there are more buttons that need loading animation, it just becomes worse. Is there anyway to refactor this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about the obvious solution, make one button that holds it's own loading state and reuse it 4 times?

Comment: It should not work properly, because I want the loading animation to be just for the button when doing its specific task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One clean way is to use React hook useReducer adding more states will be easier and more clean.
To master useReducer check this blog
https://blog.logrocket.com/react-usereducer-hook-ultimate-guide/

In the React documentation React does not advice using one useState with an object of data

It advices to using multiple useState.

```html
    
    
    const initialState = {
        loading: true,
        loadingSave: false,
        loadingDelete: false,
        loadingDownload: false,
    };
   
   
   function handlingStatesReducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'setState': {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    [action.fieldName!]: action.payload,
                };
            }
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(handlingStatesReducer, initialState);
    const { loadingDownload, loadingDelete, loadingSave, loading } = state;
    
    
    /// To setState 
    
      dispatch({
                    type: "setState",
                    fieldName: "loading",
                    payload: false
                })
```

Comment: Got your idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single state with an object that contains these values.

for example:

```
const [loadingStates, setLoadingStates] = useState({
    loading: true,
    loadingSave: false,
    loadingDelete: false,
    loadingDownload: false,
});
```

for changing the values, you can use:

```
setLoadingStates(prevObject => {
    return {
        ...prevObject,
        loading: false,
    }
});
```

Hope this helps